# api versioning in wso2

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

In WSO2 API Manager v3.2.0 I published v1 of my api that has multiple paths.
(example below is shortened, the API actually has 30 different paths).

How do I publish a v2 version for just one of these paths (or resources in wso2 lingo).

I.e. I **ONLY** want to add a new v2 /status api (/xyz/v2/status),
but I don't want v2 versions of the other resources.

e.g.:

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  description: My Api
  version: v1
  title: MyApi
security:
  - default: []
paths:
  /health:
    get:
      parameters: []
      responses:
        '200':
          description: health check
  '/status/{id}':
    get:
      parameters:
        - name: id
          in: path
          required: true
          type: string
  '/update/{id}':
    post:
      parameters:
        - name: id
          in: path
          required: true
          type: string
        - in: body
          name: Payload
          description: Request Body
          required: false
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              payload:
                type: string
```

Comment: My question formulated differently.
How do I publish a v2 version of a single api path (eg /xyz/v2/status) without creating v2 versions of all other paths within the /xyz context?

Comment: This is not achievable in WSO2 API Manager out-of-the-box. When you are creating a new version of the API, all resources included will be promoted to the newer version.

Answer (score 0):

According to the WSO2 APIM 3.2.0 implementation versioning is applicable for an entire API which includes all the resources in that API and not for an individual resource. Therefore, the requirement cannot be achieved out-of-the-box. For further details refer [1].

[1] https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/reference/samples/api-versioning-sample/